# Is it safe to use MoreExecutors.directExecutor for Future.sequence?

Tags: scala, guava

Is it safe to use `MoreExecutors.directExecutor` for `Future.sequence`?

I don't want the thread that calls `Future.sequence` to block, I want one of the threads that I am waiting on to collect all the futures.

Who does the waiting for all the futures? Is it the thread who calls `Future.sequence` or is it the threads running the futures in the sequence?

Comment: What is `MoreExecutors` ?

Comment: Guava MoreExecutors

Answer (score 0):

The scala.concurrent.Future has the following signature:

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/concurrent/Future.scala#L663

Which takes an implicit ExecutionContext as the target executor. This is the threads where the Future.sequence runs on.